# only allow numbers in contenteditable elements?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation, contenteditable

How can I make [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable) elements only allow entry of numeric values?

I tried to use something like:

```
onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'
```

...on elements that are `contenteditable`, but it still allows entry of alphabetic characters.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm interested in this issue too, but particularly for on-screen keyboards of mobile devices. I'd like to get the numbers-only on-screen keyboard to pop up instead of the full keyboard.

Comment: Here's info about [Making content editable](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content)... but, while it's true that, with some coding (and lots of testing), it's possible to implement your own validation on a `contenteditable` element, but validation is a primary, **built-in feature of `<input>` elements**. It would be a lot easier to use the existing functionality rather than designing your own. Using the built-in functionality also ensures cross-platform compatibility. See [Client-side form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Why not just use an input?

```
 <input type="number">
```

If you still want to use contenteditable, you can add an event listener like so:

```
$("#myeditablediv").keypress(function(e) {
    if (isNaN(String.fromCharCode(e.which))) e.preventDefault();
});
```

This will block all characters that are not numbers (0-9)

Comment: I am sending it as a table data not a input if not it will keep expecting inputs. As for the second one, what do you mean with the `String.fromCharCode` ?

Comment: Originally e.which is just a number that points to a character. String.fromCharCode(e.which) converts the the key that was pressed into it's respective character

Comment: I tried it already but it doesn't seem to work. I used classes to define the table data and when keypress, it should execute the function but nothing happens and it is still the same. `$(".editNumber").keypress(function() {
    if (isNaN(String.fromCharCode(event.which))) event.preventDefault();
});` editNumber is my class for table data however nothing changes

Comment: you forgot to pass through the **event** parameter:

`$(".editNumber").keypress(function(event) { ...`

Comment: `isNaN(' ') === false` - If allowing the user to input a space is an issue, use `if (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) e.preventDefault();`. This will only allow char codes 48 - 57 (numbers 0 - 9). Just another point, this code will not handle copy/cut/paste and context menu changes. Just thought I would note this for any future visitors :)

Comment: The `.which` property is deprecated. Do not use this! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/which

Answer (score 8):

Salaam

This will allow only numbers

```
$('[contenteditable="true"]').keypress(function(e) {
    var x = event.charCode || event.keyCode;
    if (isNaN(String.fromCharCode(e.which)) && x!=46 || x===32 || x===13 || (x===46 && event.currentTarget.innerText.includes('.'))) e.preventDefault();
});
```

I have also tested decimals. There are three major conditions to get allowed

- Is a Number and Not delete button
- Not Space
- Not Enter Button
- Allow Decimal point only once

Let me know if you face any bug in comments

Thank you

Comment: Both `keyCode` and `charCode` are deprecated! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/charCode

Answer (score 3):

If you want to enter only 0-9 in contenteditable div then you can use this code. This code also prevent user to copy paste into the field

```
<div contenteditable id="myeditablediv"  oncopy="return false" oncut="return false" onpaste="return false">10</div>
```

Javascript

```
$("#myeditablediv").keypress(function(e) {
        if (isNaN(String.fromCharCode(e.which))) e.preventDefault();
    });
```

if you want to enter decimal points instead of a number then you can use this javascript code

```
 $("#myeditablediv").keypress(function(e) {
        var x = event.charCode || event.keyCode;
        if (isNaN(String.fromCharCode(e.which)) && x!=46) e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: The `.keyCode`, `.charCode` and `.which` properties are all deprecated. Do not use this!

Answer (score 1):

Just expanding on ElChino3312's answer to include some additional accepted keys (numpad, arrows and delete) and excludes period as I'm not allowing decimals in my case:

```
if (!(event.code.includes('Digit') || event.code.includes('Numpad') 
     || event.code === 'ArrowLeft' || event.code === 'ArrowRight' 
     || event.code === 'Backspace' || event.code === 'Delete')) 
{
   event.preventDefault()
}
```

Comment: You forgot to check for`event.shiftKey` and `event.altKey`; this let's e.g. `!` pass (shift + 1 on my keyboard). Otherwise, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth mentioning that this assumes *non-negative* integers, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Allowing numbers, the point, the backtracking

```
<div 
  on:keydown={(event) => {
    if (
      event.code.includes('Digit') ||
      event.code === 'Backspace' ||
      event.code === 'Period'
    ) {
      console.log(e)
    } else {
      event.preventDefault()
    }
  }}
>
  foo
</div>
```

Comment: This fails for numpad input, prevents the use of arrow keys, and allows the use of shift- and alt-keys.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to allow only numbers, you can use :

```
if (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) e.preventDefault();
```

If you want to enable pad numbers, use this code :

```
if (!e.key.match(/^[0-9]/g) && e.keyCode !== 8 && e.keyCode !== 46) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

The regex starts with '^' to prevent F5 to works for example. We add e.keycode 8 and 46 to avoid the prevent default on backspace/delete

This method doesn't allow decimals, you'll need to modify regex for it

Comment: The `.keyCode` and and `.which` properties are both deprecated. Do not use this!