# change input type of contentEditable cell to "number" dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

im inserting rows to a table dynamically

```
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
cell1.contentEditable = true;
```

i set the contentEditable to true but i want the input field's type to be set to number instead of the default type :"text".

Comment: you want `td` with `type="number"` or accept only number?

Comment: @ewwink type="number" so that the keyboard in my cordova app will change to numbers

Comment: you can't because that not valid attribute, `type="number"` is for `<input>`

Comment: You could try `inputmode="decimal"`, but the keyboard will not have minus sign on some platforms, only digits and decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to this post: [Contenteditable allow numbers only for editing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45072708/contenteditable-allow-numbers-only-for-editing)

In effect it appears the td object does not have type property to set so either use input or create an event handler to validate the input.

Answer (score 0):

as I said above you can't set attribute `type="number"` to `<td>`, but here example to validate the input using javascript

```js
function addTD() {
  var row = document.getElementById("myRow");
  var x = row.insertCell(0);
  x.contentEditable = true;
  x.onkeypress = function(ev) {
    if (isNaN(String.fromCharCode(ev.which))) {
      console.log('input number only');
      ev.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

```css
table,td{border:1px solid #000}
table{border-collapse:collapse}
td{display:inline-block;width:70px;text-align:center;height: 22px;}
[contenteditable=true]{background-color:#ccc}
[contenteditable=true]:focus{background-color:#ff0}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="myRow">
    <td>First</td><td>Second</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="addTD()">Add</button>
```